# Opening image files through unix system command in C

Tags: c, unix

I have a project where the user can open files by selecting them in a menu.
I have two near identical pieces of code, but one works, whereas the other doesn't:
the one that works is for opening text files through gedit ("chemin" contains the file path):

```
char buf[200];
snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"gedit %s",chemin);
system(buf);
```

And this one doesn't work when run **in** my code, but does work when run outside of it (opens .jpg files with eog - have also tried xdg with no improvement):

```
snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"eog %s",chemin);
system(buf);
```

Is there a surer way of opening .jpg files from the unix command line? Or did I forget something?
TIA

**UPDATE**
It seems the buffer only prints its first 7 characters to the command line, ie:
my file path: `./FICHIER_PROJET/basededonnee/basedeDonneefichier/IMG_RGB/21.jpg`
what the command line prints: `eog ./FI`
This only happens with these .jpg files

Comment: Describe what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: @jessica, Make sure that `buf` having valid executable cmd (Try printing `buf` before `system()`). Also, check return value of `system()`.

Comment: have you tried out to print the content of `buf` the the console (also having an eye on any trailing new lines), and copy-pasting the console output to the terminal?

Comment: @arrowd the command is run, but nothing is opened (no particular error messages seg faults etc)

Comment: It may be a path issue. Try supplying the full path to `eog`.

Comment: @Klas tried with both relative and full paths, neither work

Comment: The problem definitely shouldn't be in any of the code you're showing: https://ideone.com/V6zjN0

Comment: What *is* sizeof(buf)?

Comment: @n.m. it returns the size of my buffer (1024)

Comment: Where do you see the 7-character string? Please show **exactly** what you see on screen (textual copy-paste or a screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

The problem might come from the char '\0' that has the wrong place, try something like :

```
strncpy(buf, "eog ", 4);
strncat(buf, chemin, sizeof(chemin));
buf[4+sizeof(chemin)] = '\0';
if(system(buf) == -1){
    perror("Error with the system call ");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it... I had been using one general buffer for all my system commands. I created a new buffer just for this one and it works.